# Login is taking lot of time and more in case of locking the user | Ubuntu 22.04 |

Tags: apt, updates, login, lock

I installed Ubuntu 22.04, and for some time, I haven't used the machine for quite some time (2 months). After 2 months, I opened the machine and ran the upgrades using the package managers. Soonly, after these upgrades, I noticed that login took more time than usual, like minutes.

Now, logging in to the system takes longer than usual during startup. It takes around 1-2 mins. This gets even worse if I use the lock-user option. I am not sure how to debug these issues. Most of the packages are related to Nvidia drivers. I am apprehensive about touching the drivers, given how messy they can be if handled incorrectly.

How to restore the login times to normal?

Below is the list of packages that apt kept back.

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-tweaks grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed gzip libnvidia-cfg1-510
  libnvidia-compute-510 libnvidia-compute-510:i386 libnvidia-decode-510 libnvidia-decode-510:i386
  libnvidia-encode-510 libnvidia-encode-510:i386 libnvidia-extra-510 libnvidia-fbc1-510
  libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386 libnvidia-gl-510 libnvidia-gl-510:i386 libspeechd2
  linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-22.04 nvidia-compute-utils-510 nvidia-dkms-510
  nvidia-driver-510 nvidia-kernel-common-510 nvidia-kernel-source-510 nvidia-utils-510
  python3-speechd speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510 xwayland
```

```
➜  ~ sudo systemd-analyze blame
[sudo] password for hiccup: 
48.827s plymouth-quit-wait.service
23.858s apt-daily-upgrade.service
22.758s snapd.service
15.291s gpu-manager.service
10.302s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 8.719s networkd-dispatcher.service
 8.362s NetworkManager.service
 8.243s dev-sda2.device
 7.600s udisks2.service
 6.856s accounts-daemon.service
 6.463s gdm.service
 5.862s dev-loop25.device
 5.825s dev-loop16.device
 5.704s dev-loop19.device
 5.648s dev-loop13.device
 5.475s dev-loop17.device
 5.436s dev-loop18.device
 5.409s dev-loop20.device
 5.403s power-profiles-daemon.service
 5.401s dev-loop22.device
 5.398s dev-loop21.device
 5.216s dev-loop14.device
 5.166s dev-loop15.device
 5.020s dev-loop6.device
 5.016s dev-loop9.device
 4.816s polkit.service
 4.453s avahi-daemon.service
 4.449s bluetooth.service
 4.285s dev-loop23.device
 4.225s dev-loop8.device
 4.167s dev-loop24.device
 4.078s switcheroo-control.service
 4.071s thermald.service
 4.066s systemd-logind.service
 4.025s wpa_supplicant.service
 3.886s ModemManager.service
 3.692s dev-loop3.device
 3.664s dev-loop2.device
 3.040s dev-loop1.device
 2.777s cups.service
 2.382s dev-loop12.device
 2.351s rsyslog.service
 2.347s dev-loop4.device
 2.289s dev-loop10.device
 2.281s tlp.service
 2.218s secureboot-db.service
 2.215s dev-loop5.device
 2.131s apport.service
 1.855s preload.service
 1.818s dev-loop7.device
 1.667s snapd.apparmor.service
 1.594s man-db.service
 1.356s kerneloops.service
 1.304s update-notifier-download.service
 1.295s dev-loop0.device
 1.222s systemd-sysctl.service
 1.187s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
 1.096s snap-authy-10.mount
 1.090s grub-common.service
 1.066s snap-authy-11.mount
 1.053s snap-bare-5.mount
 1.030s apparmor.service
 1.005s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-138.mount
  995ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-146.mount
  904ms systemd-modules-load.service
  893ms keyboard-setup.service
  890ms snap-core-13425.mount
  884ms ua-timer.service
  878ms snap-core-13741.mount
  859ms snap-core18-2560.mount
  849ms snap-core18-2566.mount
  832ms snap-core20-1518.mount
  828ms snap-core20-1623.mount
  753ms apt-daily.service
  705ms user@1000.service
  624ms systemd-random-seed.service
  614ms snap-firefox-1860.mount
  599ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-161.mount
  536ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-106.mount
  535ms systemd-sysusers.service
  523ms packagekit.service
  517ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-115.mount
  515ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount
  512ms plymouth-start.service
  506ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  475ms modprobe@drm.service
  467ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  450ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
  439ms systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service
  434ms snap-hunspell\x2ddictionaries\x2d1\x2d7\x2d2004-2.mount
  421ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  418ms e2scrub_reap.service
  334ms swapfile.swap
  317ms snap-snap\x2dstore-582.mount
  274ms snap-snap\x2dstore-592.mount
  255ms upower.service
  252ms colord.service
  246ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  242ms snapd.seeded.service
  218ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-812E\x2d76A3.service
  218ms snap-snapd-16292.mount
  195ms systemd-user-sessions.service
  182ms snap-snapd-16778.mount
  179ms openvpn.service
  177ms dev-hugepages.mount
  176ms dev-mqueue.mount
  175ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  175ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  172ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-10.mount
  168ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-14.mount
  165ms modprobe@fuse.service
  165ms kmod-static-nodes.service
  164ms modprobe@configfs.service
  131ms snap-sublime\x2dtext-112.mount
  130ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  119ms apport-autoreport.service
  117ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  109ms setvtrgb.service
  102ms systemd-resolved.service
   91ms systemd-oomd.service
   90ms systemd-timesyncd.service
   86ms systemd-udevd.service
   72ms boot-efi.mount
   67ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
   67ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   63ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
   60ms ufw.service
   55ms fwupd-refresh.service
   53ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
   29ms console-setup.service
   28ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   27ms systemd-journald.service
   26ms plymouth-read-write.service
   18ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   17ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
   13ms snap-firefox-1877.mount
   10ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
   10ms rtkit-daemon.service
    9ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
    9ms alsa-restore.service
    7ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
    5ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
    5ms modprobe@ramoops.service
    5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
    3ms dev-loop26.device
    2ms snapd.socket
```

System Information

```
➜  

dragons-edge                
    description: Notebook
    product: GL502VT (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: G4N0CV******
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0.0 dmi-3.0.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=GL sku=ASUS-NotebookSKU uuid=*********
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: GL502VT
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: BSN12345*********
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: GL502VT.203
          date: 02/25/2016
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6016KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
```

Comment: Please read and clarify your question. I can not figure out what you are asking.

Comment: @David Login is taking so much time, like more than 2 mins. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of command `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: @FedKad added the output in the description

Comment: It seems very slow at startup. How about normal usage? Opening, saving files, etc. If you can [edit] your question and add info about your hardware, more people may help you. Did you look at similar questions in AskUbuntu?

Comment: @FedKad added the requested information. There were no issues once I logged into the system. It's only with the login. Yes, I looked at other questions regarding a similar issue. Nothing concrete as of now.